# Remove unwanted array from json

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel. I'm creating a json structure using a function. This is my current output:

```json
{
    "success": "1",
    "data": [
        {
            "category_type_id": 1,
            "category_type": "Study",
            "category_icon": "http://192.168.1.132:8000/images/category/study.svg"
        },
        {
            "category_type_id": 2,
            "category_type": "Sports",
            "category_icon": "http://192.168.1.132:8000/images/category/game.svg"
        },
        {
            "category_type_id": 3,
            "category_type": "Other",
            "category_icon": "http://192.168.1.132:8000/images/category/other.svg"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
$get_all_category = CategoryType::all();

return response()->json(['success' => '1', 'data' => $get_all_category]);
```

I want result without array that is started from data plz need solution

Comment: Please update your question to show the expected result. I don't understand what you mean by "result without array that is started from data".

Comment: sir just i want remove [ ] sign from my json and add { } in my json

Comment: Can you give an expected output here    and you need to edit your post     @smita patil

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the other attributes from your from your json response:

```
$get_all_category = CategoryType::all();
return response()->json($get_all_category);
```

That will return your json like this:

```
[ 
    { 
        "category_type_id": 1,
        "category_type": "Study",
        "category_icon": "http://192.168.1.132:8000/images/category/study.svg"
    },
    {
        "category_type_id": 2,
        "category_type": "Sports",
        "category_icon": "http://192.168.1.132:8000/images/category/game.svg" },
    {
        "category_type_id": 3
        "category_type": "Other",
        "category_icon": "http://192.168.1.132:8000/images/category/other.svg"
     }
]
```

If you want to keep the success atribute you can do something like this, but it would just change the old data attribute you want to get rid of to '0':

```
$get_all_category = CategoryType::all();
return response()->json(['success' =>'1', $get_all_category]);
```

Comment: I do still highly recommend sending your json like you have been doing so so the application that consumes your json response will know where to get the data from (the data attribute)